# Finding an injection from $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Z$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find an injection from $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Z$, i.e., the Cartesian product of the rationals to the integers. I know we have to handle different cases depending on whether each term in our tuple $(q_1, q_2)$ is negative or positive.

This could very well be flawed, but here is an idea I had, where $q_1 = \frac ab$ and $q_2 = \frac cd$ (both $q_1$ and $q_2$ are **reduced to lowest terms**)

**Case 1:** $f(a/b, c/d) = 2^{ac}3^{bd}$ (we are NOT multiplying a and c, neither do we multiply b and d; rather, we are **appending them together as in the concatenation of two characters**), if both terms are positive

**Case 2:**  $f(a/b, c/d) = 2^{ac}3^{bd} + 1$, if the left term is positive and the right term is negative

**Case 3:**  $f(a/b, c/d) = 2^{ac}3^{bd} + 2$, if the left term is negative and the right term is positive

**case 4:**  $f(a/b, c/d) = 2^{ac}3^{bd} + 3$, if both terms are negative

E.g. $f(1/2, -1/4) = 2^{11}\cdot 3^{24} + 1.$

Would someone please find a way to "break" my method or show it is not an injection in some way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How can one tell if 123 is 12 then 3 or 1 then 23?

Comment: Right, there is that problem I hadn't really considered. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Good afternoon to you. Please take a look at [how to format maths on MSE.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: My apologies, it is the first time I have used math stackexchange before; thank you for the link though and I will use it next time : )

Comment: Ginger, that's ok, it's just the usual practice to let the new users know that we prefer everything typeset in MathJax. I've edited your answer this time, so please let me know if I unintentionally changed meaning to what you wanted to write.

Comment: @Ennar Thank you! And the meaning is still the same, don't worry.

Answer (score 3):

You get into trouble with $f(11/3,1/3)$ vs $f(1/3,11/3)$.

Instead, think about $2^a3^b5^c7^d$ if they are all positive. Then if $a$ is negative, instead use $11^{|a|}$, and so on.

Comment: I don't think we can use 11^(-a) because we are making a function going to the integers Z...so if we have -a = -2 for instance, 11^(-2) wouldn't be an integer?

Comment: Also thank you for the alternative suggestion, it is much appreciated and makes sense why it works (I could just change the fourth prime number based on the four cases of different signs)

Comment: @Ginger, $11^{-a}\in\mathbb Z$ for negative $a$.

Comment: @Ennar Ohhh okay, that makes sense then, thank you : )

Answer (score 1):

Your method doesn't work, for the simple reason that you cannot determine where to break the concatenated string "ac" back to strings a and c.  For example, does "1012" come from "10" and "12" or does it come from "101" and "2"?

Comment: Ah, I see why that is an issue now. Thank you for correcting me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your same idea by coding 6 integers, two for the signs and four for numerators and denominators of the reduced fractions. Then put each of these as powers on six different primes.